# Have the creators of Penny Dreadful acknowledged their debt to League of Extraordinary Gentlemen?

Tags: alan-moore, penny-dreadful

How has this show even been allowed to air, without a substantial royalty cheque being whisked to Alan Moore?

I'm no copyright lawyer,  but its pretty obvious that *Penny Dreadful* is more than just a little derivative of League of Extraordinary Gentlemen. Whilst some of the literary characters are exempt from copyright law (Hence Moore's original appropriation), and Character-mashing has been done plenty of times before, this seems deliberately built on the back of *League...*

The analogues are far too similar;  retired colonial African Hunter as leader (check!), supernatural female high class courtesan (check!), American gunslinger as support (check!), Dorian Grey (Check!!)....

Did Showtime originally attempt to get the rights for League, and fail (and if so, how have they avoided the litigious ramifications of derivative work),  or have they tried to present the works as unconnected,  and hope no one notices?

Comment: Isn't this similar to "Marvel and DC steal each other's character ideas"?

Comment: If there was more than a casual similarity, there would already be lawyers at the door. They make no qualms about bleeding cash from things like this.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gGiOy4a57Eo

Comment: @Richard, I saw this too! It's the inclusion of a cowboy in Victorian London that seals it for me.  There is just no plausibility in it,  it's lifting straight out of League... I don't see Showtime Lawyers being able to say otherwise,  if pressed..

Comment: All the characters being used are in the public domain though, so I don't think there's much in the way of legal action that can be taken.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Victorian London was well-aware of the American West and there were travelling vaudeville Wild West shows that performed there. They were very popular and one was even requested to celebrate Queen Victoria's Golden Jubilee (50 years). [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_West_Shows)

Comment: Its not the Cowboy in London that I'm saying is implausible, its the deniability that studios would have in saying its wasn't derivative of *League...*. Unless they were homaging *Shanghai Knights* of course!

Comment: I thought this same thing from the first commercial I saw for the show. I think, as you have said, the issue isn't the use of specific public domain character. But it isn't even just the bringing together of such characters in a team either, even that could be satisfactorily different. To me, the big thing is that it looks like almost the exact formula from LXG. It isn't just the bringing together of a bunch of famous heroes, it's pseudonymed versions of Quartermaine, Harker, Grey, etc in the exact same roles as LXG. Suspicious to be sure.

Comment: Just for clarification:
Moore's work didn't have the Cowboy in London (Tom Sawyer).
That was only the film adaptation, and Moore had no part in that.
Moore also did not use Dorian Grey. That was, again, the movie. Personally, I see Penny Dreadful as a spiritual adaptation of League of Extraordinary Gentlemen, no matter what the producers or writers say.

Comment: Moore didn't use Dorian on the team, but his portrait DOES appear in the background. Just interesting trivia.

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive, albeit with the added difficulty of trying to prove a negative.Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Comment: You say "supernatural female high class courtesan" and yet there is no mention of The Leagues Extraordinary Gentleman's female character Mina Harker being portrayed as Vanessa's sister and killed off in Penny Dreadful. I definitely would have mentioned that somewhere in your blurb.

Answer (score 19):

The short answer is no. In this discussion of the genesis of "Penny Dreadful", Creator and Exec Producer John Logan makes repeated references to the fact that the authors and their stories are largely contemporaneous (e.g. within a sort of Victorian gothic-themed revival) which makes combining their characters a natural concept.

As far as the show being derivative of Moore's work, the reality is that mashing up victorian writers (and their respective monsters) is neither new, nor Moore's idea. He himself claimed to have been strongly influenced by Philip José Farmer's "[The Other Log of Phileas Fogg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Other_Log_of_Phileas_Fogg)" which includes Phileas Fogg, Jules Verne, Sherlock Holmes, Dorian Grey and James Moriarty

Moore was also accused of plagiarising the ideas of [Anno Draculo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Dracula#Characters_from_fiction), a book series that drew together multiple characters from Victorian gothic fiction. This book included appearances from Dracula, Frankenstein (and his monster), Allan Quartermain, Dorian Grey, Sherlock Holmes, Dr Jekyll (and Mr Hyde), etc etc.

Comment: 'Whilst some of the literary characters are exempt from copyright law (Hence Moore's original appropriation), and Character-mashing has been done plenty of times before'... thanks for expanding (helpful), but I've already addressed most of this in the question itself. As you've said, some of the Characters are mutually complimentary: the Cowboy in London is, for me, a step too far into Moore's distinct vision. I just don't see why they needed a cowboy, its almost like it's Mocking *League* directly...

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional there are no cowboys in the League of Extraordinary Gentlemen comics (and Alan Moore disowned the awful film adaptation, as he has done for most of the film adaptations of his comics).

Comment: @evilsoup - It wouldn't be a moore film if he didn't decry it at every turn...

Comment: @evilsoup I'm not familiar with the comics: but I wonder if Victor Frankenstein shows up in them? that would be another nail in the proverbial coffin.

Answer (score 9):

No, and there's no reason for them to do so. Anyone can use the characters and stories, and they don't have to pay or attribute anything. That's how public domain works. For example, in 2011/2012, there were 3 Snow White adaptations released (2 films and a TV show), and none of them had to attribute credit to the original Snow White folk tales, much less each other.

All four of the elements of similarity you mention, are from the public domain source material, which means anyone can use those elements. Anyone can use them, and not need to ask other makers of modern adaptations if it's okay. What they can't do though, is use elements introduced in those other non-public domain adaptations.

For example, *Once Upon a Time* and *Supernatural* both used *Wizard of Oz* in the last year. *Once* made use of the magic shoes, which are famously ruby red in the *Wizard of Oz* film. However, the film isn't in the public domain, only the original book is. So the magic shoes in *Once* are silver, like they were in the book; were they red, they'd be sued by Warner Bros., who own the rights to the film.  But they can use Dorothy, the Wicked Witch, etc. with no risk of being sued, as those come from the original books.

Comment: Correction, all three of the snow white adaptations claimed to be derivative of the folk tale. They all denied being based on the 'Disney' property...

Comment: @Richard Not all 3. One of them is made by Disney, via ABC.

Comment: But they certainly didn't bill it as a live action remake though...

Comment: Unlike for example; http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1661199/

Comment: Also, the SCOTUS says no attribution is needed for public domain works.  Those movies probably did for the sake of marketing. http://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/public-domain/trouble-spots/

Comment: As posted in the question, I'm aware they're Public Domain: it's more the fact of their deployment *together*, under the same premise that Moore could claim derivation from. He doesn't own the characters within, but he **does** own the copyright on his narrative concept of them uniting together in a team to take on crime (more or less). It would be up to lawyers to determine any infringement, and (given the similarites) I imagine Showtime have pretty good ones.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional - As per my answer above, uniting them to fight crime is not an original Moore idea.

Comment: Yes, and there were [litigious repercussions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_League_of_Extraordinary_Gentlemen_(film)) for this perceived plagiarism by Moore: even if it wasn't by Newman, and Moore wasn't allowed to exonerate himself personally. *Someone* sought remuneration in the case you mentioned: why not here?

Answer (score 1):

The characters are public domain, and the character mashing trope was hardly new when *League of Extraordinary Gentlemen* began publication. I have to agree with the OP though, that the similarities between *Dreadful* characters and those of *LoEG* are more than superficial. It would make sense that the producers of the former would be acquainted with the latter – or at the very least its adaptation to film, which would explain the inclusion of Dorian Gray and <strike>Tom Sawyer</strike> an American gunslinger.

I have just started watching *Dreadful* without much knowledge about the concept, but as an early reader of the *LoEG* comics I noticed the parallels immediately and thought this might be a veiled debut of [the rumoured *LoEG* TV show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_League_of_Extraordinary_Gentlemen#TV_series)... The storylines differ very much however, the two concepts just share an initial framework. *Dreadful*'s addition of Frankenstein and the Wolfman (as well as the Dracula subplot) lead the series down other paths, like the *LoEG* books spun away from the Victorian setting after the two first story arcs.

There are knowing nods and winks in *Dreadful* though: In an early scene Sir Murray tells Ms Hives that she might want to button the top of her blouse before seeing Chandler (but is quite content taking her to a soirée in a low cut evening dress later on), which could be a red herring reference to her *LoEG* counterpart who wears scarves and high collars to disguise the bitemarks on her neck.