# What are the origins and ur-examples of a "combine all mysteries and conspiracies" sub-genre?

Tags: science-fiction-genre, history-of, area51-series

One of my favorite series is "Area 51" by Robert Doherty.

Among the things that attracted me was the formula of taking all (or at least a significant amount) of the worlds mythology, weirdness, and unexplained, and building a universe framework to tie ALL those disparate points into coherent explanation - frequently involving aliens :)

There are other works that use similar formula as well (X-Files, Langdon series by Dan Brown).

What I'm interested in is how did the idea/approach (of taking disparate mythological+historical+legendary+"weird" datapoints and explaining them as unified in-universe structure) originate and develop in the modern SFF literature? Are there classically recognized early examples?

Comment: Related, not dupe; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56407/have-the-creators-of-penny-dreadful-acknowledged-their-debt-to-league-of-extraor

Comment: related trope, you might be looking for one of its sub-tropes: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HistoricalInJoke

Comment: Just to clarify - I'm looking for "origins" both in the sense of early example AND importantly **influence**.

Comment: Some other related tropes: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ConspiracyKitchenSink and http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MassiveMultiplayerCrossover

Comment: One more good recent example of this genre: the Warehouse 13 series.

Answer (score 3):

One very influential work in the genre of [conspiracy fiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conspiracy_fiction) was [The Illuminatus! Trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Illuminatus!_Trilogy) by Robert Anton Wilson and Robert Shea, published in 1975. It's an intentionally absurd blend of a huge number of conspiracy theories, both real (many inspired by letters from conspiracy theorists that Wilson got when working at Playboy) and invented by the authors. A paragraph from [this review](http://www.conceptualfiction.com/illuminatus_trilogy.html) about the book's version of the Kennedy assassination gives a flavor:

> Readers of The Illuminatus! Trilogy learn, for example, that John
>   Dillinger, the infamous bank robber killed by the FBI outside a movie
>   theater in 1934, actually survived the incident and turned up with a
>   gun at Dealey Plaza on November 22,
>   1963.  But he was late to the event:  several other organizations had already placed operatives on the scene with orders to shoot the
>   President —and the real question, according to Wilson and Shea, isn't
>   who planned the assassination of JFK, but which gunman managed to pull
>   the trigger first.    But if you seek ultimate answers, you need to
>   dig below the scene of the crime, to the underground lair of the
>   Dealey Lama, whose office is located under the sewers of Dallas.  He’s
>   a wise robed and bearded man who presides over a powerful secret
>   society, and is perhaps more influential than either the President or
>   conspirators up on ground level.

But as the review also notes, the books are designed to mess with your sense of reality in a sort of psychedelic, '60s counterculture style:

> Yet as I look back at my description of this book, I realize that I
>   have misled you.  Because this book is just as serious as it is
>   absurd.  Even as Shea and Wilson pile up ludicrous incidents on top of
>   one another, they also want to convey words of wisdom.  As strange as
>   it sounds, given my summary above, The Illuminatus! Trilogy wants to
>   possess the authority of non-fiction.    The authors add footnotes and
>   appendices, and work hard to substantiate many of their claims with
>   citations and evidence.  Not all of the sources are real ones—I am
>   rightly skeptical when any author backs up claims with references to
>   the Necronomicon by the "mad Arab" Abdul Alhazred.   But much of the
>   documentation withstands scrutiny.   Shea and Wilson add to the
>   peculiar flavor of their work by frequently inserting long passages
>   that can only be described as a counterculture philosophy of life. 
>   When you reach the final pages of this work, you will find that your
>   greatest challenge as a reader is not evaluating the literary merits
>   of the trilogy, but determining how much of it the authors themselves
>   actually believe—and, by extension, how much credence you ought to
>   give to their claims.

Answer (score 2):

C.S. Lewis (of Narnia fame) wrote a series of novels in the 1930s which he called "[The Space Trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Space_Trilogy)". One of the key themes of these novels was that the supposed *mythology* of the ancient Greek and Roman world actually reflects the interplanetary politics of our own Solar System:

> Ransom gets much information on cosmology from the Oyarsa (presiding
>   angel) of Malacandra, or Mars. Maleldil, the son of the Old One, ruled
>   the Field of Arbol, or solar system, directly. But then the Bent One
>   (the Oyarsa of Earth) rebelled against Maleldil and all the eldila
>   (similar to the Valar in Tolkien's Silmarillion) of Deep Heaven (outer
>   space).

In a [letter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Space_Trilogy#Influences_and_approach), Lewis described the book thusly:

> I like the whole **interplanetary ideas as a mythology** and simply wished
>   to conquer for my own (Christian) p[oin]t of view what has always
>   hitherto been used by the opposite side.

---

A more recent example of a [meta-mythology](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AMythologyIsTrue) would be [The Other Log of Phileas Fogg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Other_Log_of_Phileas_Fogg). It was originally written in 1971 and included a wide variety of mythological beings as well as fictional characters.

> The story takes place within the internal reality first imagined in
>   the 1872 Jules Verne novel, Around the World in Eighty Days. Farmer
>   includes many of the story's original characters, including the
>   eponymous Phileas Fogg as well as his French valet, Passepartout. He
>   also establishes that all of Verne's published works take place within
>   the same shared continuity including Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the
>   Sea. In addition, he includes other elements of crossover fiction,
>   incorporating the Arthur Conan Doyle characters of Sherlock Holmes and
>   James Moriarty into his setting. These elements place Phileas Fogg and
>   his entire supporting cast into the Wold Newton family of literary
>   characters.